# "Более чем" как наречие

Tags: наречия, пунктуация

"Я более чем прав". Является ли в этом предложении конструкция "более чем" наречной? По-моему, можно заменить словом "полностью".
Или в диалоге, например:
- Я прав?
- Более чем.
Как думаете, ведь от этого зависит постановка запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетание *более чем* в данном случае означает *совершенно, в высшей степени.* Запятая не нужна. Если бы здесь был сравнительный оборот с союзом *чем*, то запятая была бы нужна. Так что Вы действительно правы. Более чем.

Comment: А является ли "более чем" наречным словосочетанием?

Comment: Думаю, да.